# Modification of a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2 lists that consist of 4 lists of 2 floating numbers, for example:

```
L1 = [ [0,1], [3,4], [2,5], [4,1] ] 
L2 = [ [4,3], [3,5], [2,2], [1,3] ]
```

How can I reshape this to:

```
L_combined = [[L1 first index of each sublist],
              [L2 first index of each sublist],
              [L1 second index of each sublist],
              [L2 second index of each sublist]]
```

To be clear, this should result in:

```
[[0,3,2,4], 
 [4,3,2,1],
 [1,4,5,1], 
 [3,5,2,3]]
```

How would I do this for the general case of combining:

```
L1 = [[1, 2, .. Y], [1, 2, .. Y] ...]
L2 = [[1, 2, .. Y], [1, 2, .. Y] ...]
...
LX = [[1, 2, .. Y], [1, 2, .. Y] ...]
```

Into

```
L_combined = [[L1 first index of each sublist],
              [L2 first index of each sublist],
              [....]
              [....],
              [LX Yth index of each sublist]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `zip()` in Python.

Comment: How easy it was if you stated the expected output rather than some English words to describe the output!! Please also show us the code you tried.

Comment: Are the lists in every top-level list guaranteed to have the same length?

Comment: @CharlesLandau yes

Comment: @Austin because I think it is easier than writing 100 lines :/

Comment: Does it have to use list comprehensions? You can do it with numpy array manipulations. Also why is this tagged pandas and numpy?

Comment: @vmg list comprehension is faster than appending for instance but if there are ways that are more optimal Please share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
output = [[i[0] for i in list1], [i[0] for i in list2], [i[1] for i in list1], [i[1] for i in list2]]
```

You can extend this using:

```
lsts = [lst1, lst2, lst3 ...]

output = [[j[k]  for j in i] for k in range(len(lsts[0][0])) for i in lsts]
```

**THIS IS ASSUMING ALL THE LISTS ARE THE SAME LENTGH**

Input:

```
lst1 = [['a11', 'a21', 'a31'],['a12', 'a22', 'a32'],['a13', 'a23', 'a33']]
lst2 = [['b11', 'b21', 'b31'],['b12', 'b22', 'b32'],['b13', 'b23', 'b33']]
lst3 = [['c11', 'c21', 'c31'],['c12', 'c22', 'c32'],['c13', 'c23', 'c33']]
```

Outputs:

```
[['a11', 'a12', 'a13'], ['b11', 'b12', 'b13'], ['c11', 'c12', 'c13'], ['a21', 'a22', 'a23'], ['b21', 'b22', 'b23'], ['c21', 'c22', 'c23'], ['a31', 'a32', 'a33'], ['b31', 'b32', 'b33'], ['c31', 'c32', 'c33']]
```

Comment: @Spenrose give me a sec. I'm typing it out :)